# Errors when launching Windows 10 installation from grub

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, windows, uefi

My problem is that I have an Asus Zen book that I am trying to return through amazon after installing ubuntu on it. I am trying to get it back as close to the original as possible and this requires re-installing windows 10. I have created a partition on it that contains the files included in the Windows 10 iso I downloaded from Microsoft. I then added this code to grub.cfg on my main partition:

```
menuentry 'Windows 10 Install Disk' {
set root=(hd0,5)
insmod part_msdos
insmod ntfs
insmod ntldr
drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
ntldr /bootmgr
}
```

(This is a copy and paste I know nothing about grub, though i'm trying to learn)
I then booted and accessed the grub screen and selected "Windows 10 Install Disk" and this is what I get before the main grub screen reappears:

```
error: file '/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/ntldr.mod' not found.
error: can't find command 'drivemap'.
error: can't find command 'ntldr'.

Press any key to continue...
```

Any solutions would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a recovery media for Windows 10(or if you have created one on your own)-you can simply recover Windows 10 using that. It will wipe out Ubuntu Linux. At the time of recovery it will be asking you to restore the laptop to it's factory settings - just make use of it.

I believe any PC manufacturer will anyway reset the system to the factory settings - so you can check with them and stop putting any efforts towards it if that is the case.

You might still be having the recovery partition for this laptop. You can contact ASUS support in terms of how to recover the system to it's factory settings using that.

Comment: I unfortunately have no recovery medium but this is still very helpful as I hadn't thought of the fact that they would have to reset them anyways for security and what not.

Comment: Contact ASUS support to reset the system to it's factory setting using the recovery partition if that is not wiped out.  If this solves your issue...accept this as an answer by clicking the tick against it.